# Adding new row in Form Array with Reactive Form Angular

Tags: angular, forms, angular-forms

I'm trying to add multiple cars dynamically on my form.

For now this code is the closest I have to the solution:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-group-with-formarray-adding-dyamic-row-angular-5-6

But what I need is to have only one `form-group`, and when entering a car info and pressing `Add New`, the car data appears as a table row below.

When pressing submit form the inserted data must be as in the example:

```
{
  "details": [
    {
      "type": "Opel",
      "model": "Astra",
      "year": "2001",
      "make": null,
      "color": "red",
      "plateNumber": "10239dfc"
    },
    {
      "type": "Renault",
      "model": "Clio",
      "year": "2008",
      "make": null,
      "color": "Yellow",
      "plateNumber": "384818ccc"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Do you have any link, doc, or something to help me solve this? I just need some guide! Thanks!!

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray

Answer (score 0):

try this... In you ts file

```
 this.yrForm= this._fb.group({

   Details: this._fb.array(
      [this.allArrayData()]
    )
  });




   allArrayData() {
      return this._fb.group({
        quantity: [''],
        percentage: ['']
      });
    };
      addNewOffer() {

  const control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls['discount'];
  control.push(this.initlanguage());

}
```

now in your Html file...

```
     <div formArrayName="Details">
        <div *ngFor="let language of myForm['controls'].discount['controls'] ; let i=index" class="double-input"
        [formGroupName]="i">
         <input type="text" formControlName="yrFrmCTRLname...">

         <button (click)="addNewOffer()">addd</button>
          <path
     </div>
```

it may helps you...let me know if you need help thankyou

Comment: need to clarify more.....like this.initlanguage() method need to define